# List issue with <li> tag

Tags: html

I've made a list with `<li>` tags which looks like this.

https://gyazo.com/764cbe3542522bc552d774e1383ac810

Why is there a random `<li>` tag down there? There is nothing there to say at all?

```html
<center>
    <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
        <div class="cover-container">
            <div class="inner cover" style="text-align:left;margin-top:30px;">
                <div class="card card-outline-primary">
                    <div class="card-header card-primary">
                        Database breaches
                    </div>
                    <div class="card-block">
                        <p>Here is a list of all databases that have been added to our search engine.</p>
                        <li>
                            <p>
                                <?php
                                    $this->load->database();
                                    $this->db->from('databases');
                                    $query = $this->db->get();
                                    foreach($query->result() as $q) {
                                ?>
                                <?=$q->Website?> hacked on
                                <?=$q->Date?> with
                                <?=$q->Users?> users
                                <br />
                                <li>
                                    <p>
                                        <?php 
                                            }
                                        ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</center>
```

Comment: It wasn't possible to format your code?

Comment: if you've made the list, just remove the li. I didn't understand the issue.

Comment: @RicardoPontual please check the screenshot and you'll see the problem. and I want the <li> to make it look moren nice to the list

Comment: you're closing out the </li>...?

Comment: <?=$q->Website?> hacked on <?=$q->Date?> with <?=$q->Users?> users 
         <br />
              **<li>**
         <p>

Comment: TwoDen, I answered it, but gave me a downvote

Comment: FYI <center> is old deprecated HTML. Use css instead

Answer (score 0):

Here is a version of your exact code but I ran the "tidy" function in the snippet. See how it's broken?

You're not closing things properly, see the code comments. Also, you're incorrectly nesting the tags, the `li` is closed before the `p` even though it starts before it.

Technically, you're adding a new `li` element when you're trying to close the tag because instead of `</li>` you're doing `<li>`.

```html
<center>
  <div class="site-wrapper-inner">
    <div class="cover-container">
      <div class="inner cover" style="text-align:left;margin-top:30px;">
        <div class="card card-outline-primary">
          <div class="card-header card-primary">
            Database breaches
          </div>
          <div class="card-block">
            <p>Here is a list of all databases that have been added to our search engine.</p>
            <li>
              <p>
                <?php $this->load->database(); $this->db->from('databases'); $query = $this->db->get(); foreach($query->result() as $q) { ?>
                <?=$q->Website?> hacked on
                  <?=$q->Date?> with
                    <?=$q->Users?> users
                      <br />
                      <li> <!-- NOT A CLOSING TAG -->
                        <p> <!-- NOT A CLOSING TAG, ALSO SHOULD BE BEFORE THE CLOSING LI TAG -->
                          <?php } ?>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</center>
```